# Unexpected behavior of my website when I upload it to my domain

Tags: html, css, cpanel

I have been working on a website. And I uploaded the website to Cpanel once it was completed. It was working completely fine, but I made some changes to the website and again uploaded, now the website on the domain is having increases font size and video sizes, but if I run the same website on my localhost ( IDE) it works exactly how it is supposed to do. Please help me out here, I am out of thoughts.

Comment: Might be a simple cache-problem. Try to visit the page in incognito-mode of your browser. Then investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

May need some more information, but it sounds like you have some references to some style sheet(or something like that) on your local machine that may not be on your domain.

In other words, your website may be pointing to style references on your local machine and not the domain.

if your local ide is showing a style sheet for example at c://mywebsite/styles.css, you need to make sure your website is not refereng to c://mywebsite/ but www.whatever-your-domain-is.com/styles.css

Just a thought, may not be the issue without further info, but I would start there.

Comment: Well the css I was using was the right one but never mind, I made the website from scratch and now it works well, Thanks for the response